# Securing registration for Asp.net core Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

I am creating a Xamarin app and intent to use Asp.net core (2.2 for now) identity for user login.  Users can register via the app, which simply posts a json

{Username:"MyNewUser@blahblah.com", password ....... } etc

To the registration endpoint in my asp.net identity. This creates the user in the database. My question is, how would I stop a malicious user or bot filling my database with fake users? How can I protect the user registration process if it is  an unauthenticated endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the most easily and useful way to protect the user registration process is enabled Email confirm.

If one user has registered, he need click the Email confirm link firstly to enable the user account. Like this :

If you don't want to modify the register process, I suggest you could write a custom middleware to check the user IP address or request header user-agent to avoid one user register multiple time. More details about how to write a custom middleware, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

About how to enable Email confirm, you could refer to this [article](https://code-maze.com/email-confirmation-aspnet-core-identity/).

[image]